# Has angular changed recently to require adding modules and controllers via functions?

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular v1.3.13.  Version1 does not work in Chrome:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

    <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

> Argument 'HelloWorldCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Version2 works fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app=myApp>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

    <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         angular.module('myApp', []).controller('HelloWorldCtrl',
            function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Version1 is the original code from a [Pluralsight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-fundamentals).  In the course the code works fine.  Did I make an error or does this no longer work due to changes in AngularJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Using global functions is not supported anymore. But it's been quite a long time: [since 1.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-21)

Answer (score 2):

From angularV1.3 to use functions defined on window scope as controllers we need call alloGlobals method defined on $controllerProvider.

```
module.config(function($controllerProvider){  
        $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();  
    });
```

[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider) 
[changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-21)